# Error when trying to insert data to a SQL Server database through a C# application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SALE7\\SALE7;Initial Catalog=YOUTUBE;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES (@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)", cs);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LASTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

    cs.Open();
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Error occurs here
    cs.Close();
}
```

The exception detail:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Comment: what is the table structure and number of not null columns in the table.

Comment: How many columns does the `tblContacts` table have? If it has more than 2, you have to specify to which columns you want to insert your values, like in: `INSERT INTO tblContacts (column_name1, column_name2) VALUES (@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)`

Comment: 3 columns all are null.

Comment: Then, as I said, you have to specify the names of the two columns in which you want the values to be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you may have more than two columns in your table but you have missed to include

```
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblContacts(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) VALUES (@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)", cs);
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception is telling you what is wrong:

Your table does not have two columns (my guess: it has more).

So, if you just have an ID element with autoincrement, you may change your Command to

```
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblContacts (firstname,lastname) VALUES (@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)", cs);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use insert query like this

```
INSERT INTO tblContacts(first_name_column_name, last_name_column_name) VALUES (@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)
```

this error raised because you have more than 2 columns in your table and database couldn't know which columns you try to fill

Answer (score 0):

You might have more the more than two column as you specify.
use query like:

Insert INTO tblContacts(firstname,lastname) VALUES (@firstname,@lastname)